# React Resolve Error : Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, npm

I am pretty new to typescript and recently tried to build a few react pages using ts, however have had a host of problems trying to get it to get it all working.

I am currently trying to integrate react (using typescript) into an existing asp.net core application and have imported the modules using npm. However trying to load the page I receive an uncaught typeerror:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react".
> Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

My guess here is that the "node_modules" libs are not being made accessible at runtime and need to somehow be in the wwwroot folder (but I may be wrong). Currently the node_modules folder is at the same directory level as the wwwroot folder.

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "lib": ["ES6", "dom"],
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "outDir": "../wwwroot/js/",
        "jsx": "react"
    }
}
```

npm packages:

```
├── @types/bootstrap@5.0.17
├── @types/jquery@3.5.6
├── @types/node@16.4.3
├── @types/react-dom@17.0.9
├── @types/react@17.0.15
├── commonjs@0.0.1
├── react-dom@17.0.2
├── react@17.0.2
└── typescript@4.3.5
```

Razor Page:

```
@page
@using System.Data
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html
@model TestSite.Form
@{
  ViewData["Title"] = " Form";
}

<div>
  <div id='FormContent'></div>
  <script type="module" src="/js/Builder/Form.js"></script>
</div>
```

Form.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class Form extends React.Component
{

    constructor()
    {
        super();
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <div>
                <b>Test</b>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

render(
    <Form />,
    document.getElementById('FormContent')
);
```

Any ideas on this one?

Many Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Could you pls offer the tutorial document here? It seems that you missed some steps to make your project down. This [tutorial](https://reactjs.net/tutorials/aspnetcore.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! :)

I mostly read the API docs rather than a tutorial. However yes I actually saw this one after I post and specifically the phrase:

"Heads up! This configuration only supports globally-scoped modules. If you're planning on using require or import module syntax in your application, use the reactnet-webpack template instead for webpack support. "

Is probably the issue!

Going to give it a go with webpack and see if that helps and report back! :)

Comment: So webpack not really the best option sadly as It would require some pretty major restructuring of my propjects and not great documentation for getting this going with Asp .Net Core 5 MVC..

I can "solve" (sortof) the problem by placing the react libs in the wwwroot folder and manually referencing them in the import as instructed.. However typescript then complains it cannot find the types..

Is there a way to manually specify where the types are as at current I am using CDN links and only download the types in node...?